# Backing up farm with shared Database

Tags: backup

I apologize if this has been asked and answered already but I couldn't find an answer.

We have four Sharepoint Foundation servers that all use a fifth server to store their SQL database. We'll call them SP1, SP2, SP3, SP4 and SQLSTORE.

The four servers all have completely different sets of sites/IIS/certificates/etc. They all have the same version of Windows and Sharepoint and everything, and they are all on the same domain. They just host different sites.

I need to back them all up, but I have a few (admittedly-newbie) questions: 
1- Does this count as one farm or four?
2- If this is one farm (and I believe it is), if I do a farm level backup from, say, SP1, do I need to do another from SP2, SP3, and SP4, or will the SP1 backup include the others? Will it include everything? (e.g., IIS)?
3- Would I also need to do a SQL backup on SQLSTORE?

The only other thing I could think was that each server would back up it's own portion of the SQL database, but I don't think that's possible (nor do I think I'd be able to recover from it anyway).

In short.. What's the best way to go about getting this backed up?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just because servers share a SQL server does not make them a farm. You would need to connect to SP-CA and via "Manage Servers on this farm" link check which other servers you see.

Backups are of different types, full farm back (assuming you have 1 farm) can be fully performed again via SP-CA using Backup full or via PowerShell - see here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428295(v=office.14).aspx also more tips http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1040

If you are only interested in Content you could set for SQL Content database backup, but otherwise, if you are unsure, go for Full